# jquery hover infinite loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My page displays an image. When the user hovers their mouse on the image, I want to transfer that image to a center picture frame. Here is a demo: http://techfeed.net/dyany.com/

As you can see, my code keeps transferring the image to the picture frame over and over. I only want this transfer to happen once. I've googled and found mention of using the stop() function, but this doesn't seem to work for me (and it seems to have a different purpose anyway.)

The CSS looks like this:

```
.genealogy {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
.ui-effects-transfer {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px dashed purple;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
}
.pictureFrame {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    left: 400px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="demo">
    <img src="images/genealogy.png" id="imageSmall" class="genealogy" onClick="displayImage()" />
    <div class="pictureFrame" id="picFrame"></div>
</div>
```

And finally, the JavaScript:

```
function runTransfer() {
    var options = {};
    options = {
        to: "#picFrame",
        className: "ui-effects-transfer"
    };

    // run the effect
    $("#imageSmall").effect("transfer", options, 1000, afterTransfer);
};

function afterTransfer() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#picFrame").append('<img src="images/genealogyLarge.png">');
        $("#imageSmall").hide();
    }, 0);
};

// set effect from select menu value
$("#imageSmall").hover(function() {
    runTransfer();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried dumping my code in and it made a big mess...just a sec.

Comment: why are doing `var options = {};` ?

Comment: I don't know, ilia choly. :) I'm still trying to learn jQuery. I removed that line and it still works.

Comment: ok but make sure to put stick a `var` in there. otherwise you'll be putting it in the global namespace.

Comment: Yup, I had a var in there (I had combined the two lines really...I didn't just delete the first one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your `hover` callback is being called multiple times. First it is called when your mouse goes over the small image, then you create an element above your thumbnail (i.e. between the mouse and your thumbnail). Then that element moves and you get another hover. Rinse and repeat until the first animation finishes and makes the thumbnail go away.

Switching to [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one) should sort you out:

```
$('#imageSmall').one('mouseover', function() {
    runTransfer();
});
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tsKnz/

If all you want to do is call `runTransfer` (and `runTransfer` doesn't take any arguments), you could just do this:

```
$('#imageSmall').one('mouseover', runTransfer);
```

And an example of this version: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tsKnz/1/

Comment: @Jake: You should be able to use just `$('#imageSmall').one('mouseover', runTransfer);` if you want. Or keep using the standard anonymous function pattern if that's more familiar.

Comment: if I do that, the transfer runs automatically instead of waiting until I mouseover.

Comment: @Jake: Are you doing `$('#imageSmall').one('mouseover', runTransfer);` or `$('#imageSmall').one('mouseover', runTransfer());`?

Comment: I can't remember...I've since changed that code and it looks a lot different now. But thanks for continuing to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript : Not 60 lines

```
var moved = false; 
document.querySelector('ur pic').addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
if(!moved){
     moved = true; //Do the rest to move it 
}},false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    $(function() {
        function runTransfer() {
            var options = {};
        options = { to: "#picFrame", className: "ui-effects-transfer" };
                    // run the effect

          $( "#imageSmall" ).effect( "transfer", options, 1000, afterTransfer );
        };

        function afterTransfer() {

          setTimeout(function() {

            $("#picFrame").append('<img src="images/genealogyLarge.png">');

            $( "#imageSmall" ).hide();

          }, 0 );

        };

        // set effect from select menu value

       $("#imageSmall").hover(function() {
          $("#imageSmall").unbind("hover");
          runTransfer();
          return false;
       });

  });
```